# How to provide/inject into Vue root instance WITH nuxt and @vue/composition-api?

Tags: typescript, nuxt.js, vue-apollo, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I'm trying to use [@vue/apollo-composable](https://v4.apollo.vuejs.org/guide-composable/setup.html#_1-install-vue-apollo-composable) with my Nuxt-Ts application. This is the example how it should be injected into root instance on a "normal" Vue application:

```
import { provide } from '@vue/composition-api'
import { DefaultApolloClient } from '@vue/apollo-composable'

const app = new Vue({
  setup () {
    provide(DefaultApolloClient, apolloClient)
  },

  render: h => h(App),
})
```

**Problem:** I don't know how to get access to the root instance **in Nuxt-TS**.

I tried making a plugin, but it's injected either directly into the root instance (which is not right, because `@vue/apollo-composable` is using [`composition-api::provide()`](https://vue-composition-api-rfc.netlify.com/#plugin-development) which creates it's own property `_provided`.

And if I use nuxt plugin's `inject` a `$` get's concatenated. And if I write a `_provided` object directly in via `ctx.app._provided =` it doesn't stick.

```
import { DefaultApolloClient } from "@vue/apollo-composable";
const myPlugin: Plugin = (context, inject) => {
  const defaultClient = ctx.app.apolloProvider.defaultClient;
  inject(DefaultApolloClient.toString(), defaultClient) // results in $$ and also composition-api::inject is checking inside `_provided[DefaultApolloClient]`
}

export default myPlugin
```

I can't call `provide()` like in the original example, because it's only allowed inside a `VueComponent::setup` function.

I also tried creating a Component and just use it on the page I need it (kind of defeats the purpose of installing in root instance though)

```
const InstallGraphQl = createComponent({
  name: "InstallGraphQl",
  setup(_props, ctx: any) {
    debugger;
    const apolloClient = ctx.app.apolloProvider.defaultClient;
    ctx.provide(DefaultApolloClient, apolloClient);
  },
});
export default createComponent({
  name: "DefaultLayout",
  components: {
    InstallGraphQl
  },
  setup(_props, _ctx: SetupContext) {
    const { result } = useQuery(SharedLayoutQuery);
    return { result };
  },
});
```

but then `setup` of the exported components gets called before `InstallGraphQl::setup`...

Edit: Also for more information about `@vue/apollo-composable` see discussion here: https://github.com/vuejs/vue-apollo/issues/687

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just set a `setup()` to the root options:

```js
/* plugins/provide-apollo-client.js */

import {provide} from '@vue/composition-api'
import {DefaultApolloClient} from '@vue/apollo-composable'

export default function ({app}) {
  app.setup = () => {
    provide(DefaultApolloClient, ...)
  }

  // Or, use local mixin
  app.mixins = (app.mixins || []).concat({
    setup () {...},
  })
}
```

```js
/* nuxt.config.js */

export default {
  plugins: ['~/plugins/provide-apollo-client'],
}
```

Not much familiar with nuxt-ts though, but I think the code should just work.

Comment: Although @Austio brought me in the right direction, calling `provide()` inside my `default.vue::setup()` triggered an out of memory error. (I think because it keeps reloading because I'm also query for `loggedInUser` in my `default.vue`)

And I also think putting `provide(DefaultApolloClient,..)` inside it's own file and not in `default.vue` is the more correct approach.

Answer (score 3):

I don't use nuxt-ts but i do have this setup in a nuxt application.  In my default.vue template i provide like this.

```
<script>
  import { provide } from '@vue/composition-api';
  import { ApolloClients } from '@vue/apollo-composable'

  export default {
    setup(props, context) {
      provide(ApolloClients, {
        default: context.root.$apollo,
      })
    }
  }
</script>
```

Package versions are

```
"@vue/apollo-composable": "4.0.0-alpha.1"
"@vue/composition-api": "version": "0.3.4"
```

Apollo Setup

```
//apolloClient.js
import { ApolloClient } from 'apollo-client';
import { InMemoryCache } from 'apollo-cache-inmemory';
import link from './link';

export default function apolloClient(_, inject) {
  const cache = new InMemoryCache();

  const client = new ApolloClient({
    // Provide required constructor fields
    cache,
    link,
    // Provide some optional constructor fields
    name: 'apollo-client',
    queryDeduplication: false,
    defaultOptions: {
      watchQuery: {
        fetchPolicy: 'cache-and-network',
      },
    },
  });

  inject('apollo', client);
}

// link.js
import { split } from 'apollo-link';
import { HttpLink } from 'apollo-link-http';
import { WebSocketLink } from 'apollo-link-ws';
import { getMainDefinition } from 'apollo-utilities';
import fetch from 'unfetch';
const httpLink = new HttpLink({
  uri: 'http://localhost:8080/v1/graphql',
  credentials: 'same-origin',
  fetch,
});

const wsParams = {
  uri: `ws://localhost:8080/v1/graphql`,
  reconnect: true,
};

if (process.server) {
  wsParams.webSocketImpl = require('ws');
}

const wsLink = new WebSocketLink(wsParams);

// using the ability to split links, you can send data to each link
// depending on what kind of operation is being sent
const link = split(
  // split based on operation type
  ({ query }) => {
    const definition = getMainDefinition(query);
    return (
      definition.kind === 'OperationDefinition' &&
      definition.operation === 'subscription'
    );
  },
  wsLink,
  httpLink,
);

export default link;
```

Then with the above, you include apollo in your nuxtconfig as a plugin

```
  plugins: [
    '~/plugins/vue-composition-api',
    '~/plugins/apolloClient'
  ],
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, that seems to be the only way at this time that works? But how do you configure apollo? Because although I get an default apolloClient, it's still empty instead of populated with my settings from `nuxt.config.ts`. are you using "@nuxt/vue-apollo" to create `context.root.$apollo` in the first hand?

Comment: Awesome will post over, his approach with setup is much better!

Answer (score 1):

There is now an official [onGlobalSetup](https://composition-api.now.sh/helpers/onGlobalSetup.html) helper for this in `nuxt-composition-api`

According to the documentation, you simply use it in a plugin like so:

```
import { onGlobalSetup } from 'nuxt-composition-api'

export default () => {
  onGlobalSetup(() => {
    provide('globalKey', true)
  })
}
```

Comment: ah, good to know. Sadly I can't use `nuxt-composition-api`, it always throws an error when I finally build nuxt. to be fair I'm using `nuxt-ts` so it probably isn't made for typescript yet...

Comment: I stopped using `nuxt-ts` as it's not recommended for production and bloats memory usage, plus I ran into some strange issues..

Comment: yeah, it has defintily been a hassle. but better than not using typescript...

may I asked what else you are using now?

Comment: I still use `@nuxt/typescript-build` but not the runtime that allows using TS in nuxt.config.

Comment: ah, gotcha. I will have to look into it. did you have to modify your webpack file to make nuxt work with components in ts? any chance you got a link handy? thx!

Comment: The [Nuxt TypeScript setup](https://typescript.nuxtjs.org/guide/setup.html) works OOTB, simply don't configure the [runtime](https://typescript.nuxtjs.org/guide/runtime.html) and keep `nuxt.config.js` as JS and components should work fine in TS.

Comment: Thanks, seems I should have paid more attention to the `optional` while setting it up! I will give it a spin, but I will have to backport my `modules` and `serverMiddleware` to JS before that.