# How to add @vue/apollo-composable to Quasar Frramework

Tags: javascript, vue.js, apollo, apollo-client, quasar-framework

We're trying to add a boot file to Quasar Framwework to be able to use `@vue/apollo-composable` with the Vue composition API. [This tutorial](https://medium.com/quasar-framework/adding-apollo-client-to-quasar-5da265719dc8) explains how that is done for the old apollo-client and [this one](https://dev.to/n_tepluhina/vue-apollo-v4-the-first-look-c32) for the new version.

The issue we're having is to connect the Apollo client to Vue. So we need to translate the [example from the docs](https://v4.apollo.vuejs.org/guide-composable/setup.html#_1-install-vue-apollo-composable) to a Quasar boot file:

```js
// example docs
import { provide } from '@vue/composition-api'
import { DefaultApolloClient } from '@vue/apollo-composable'

const app = new Vue({
  setup () {
    provide(DefaultApolloClient, apolloClient)
  },

  render: h => h(App),
})
```

The Quasar boot file:

```js
import { createHttpLink } from 'apollo-link-http'
import { InMemoryCache } from 'apollo-cache-inmemory'
import { ApolloClient } from 'apollo-client'
import { DefaultApolloClient } from '@vue/apollo-composable'
import { provide } from '@vue/composition-api'

const httpLink = createHttpLink({
  uri: 'http://localhost:4000/graphql',
})

const cache = new InMemoryCache()

const apolloClient = new ApolloClient({
  link: httpLink,
  cache
});

export default async ({ app } /* { app, router, Vue ... } */) => {
  app.setup(provide(DefaultApolloClient, apolloClient))
}
```

The issue:

[image]

What is the correct syntax to use in the Quasar Framework boot file to add the Apollo client?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the correct syntax in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59198021/how-to-provide-inject-into-vue-root-instance-with-nuxt-and-vue-composition-api/59270760#59270760):

```js
import { boot } from 'quasar/wrappers'
import { createHttpLink } from 'apollo-link-http'
import { InMemoryCache } from 'apollo-cache-inmemory'
import { ApolloClient } from 'apollo-client'
import { DefaultApolloClient } from '@vue/apollo-composable'
import { provide } from '@vue/composition-api'
import config from 'src/app-config.json'

export default boot(({ app }) => {
  const httpLink = createHttpLink({
    uri: config.resources.gatewayApi.uri,
  })

  const cache = new InMemoryCache()

  const apolloClient = new ApolloClient({
    link: httpLink,
    cache,
  })

  app.setup = () => {
    provide(DefaultApolloClient, apolloClient)
    return {}
  }
})
```

Comment: Instead of `app.setup = () => { ... }` it better to use `app.mixins = (app.mixins || []).concat({ setup() { ... } });` so you won't break setup chain with other boot files where `setup` method called.

Answer (score 1):

I translated @DarkLite1's code to be TypeScript compatible. So following is the file `src/boot/vue-apollo-4.ts` (don't forget to register it in `quasar.conf.js`):

```
<pre>
import { createHttpLink } from 'apollo-link-http'
import { InMemoryCache } from 'apollo-cache-inmemory'
import { ApolloClient } from 'apollo-client'
import { DefaultApolloClient } from '@vue/apollo-composable'
import { provide } from '@vue/composition-api'
import { boot } from 'quasar/wrappers'

const httpLink = createHttpLink({
  uri: 'http://localhost:8080/v1/graphql'
})

const cache = new InMemoryCache()

const apolloClient = new ApolloClient({
  link: httpLink,
  cache
})

export default boot(({ app }) => {
  app.setup = () => {
    provide(DefaultApolloClient, apolloClient)
    return {}
  }
})
</pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

try use this :

```
export default ({ app, Vue }) => {
  Vue.use(VueApollo)
  app.apolloProvider = apolloProvider
}
```